# use wordpress to create user on external database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

let me try to explian what i wanna achieve, I have wordpress site and a project management system from codecanyon here is the link.
http://codecanyon.net/item/freelance-manager/1225423

The project management system not allowed registration for users. But only admin can make users from admin panel. The users can only register through wordpress. For registration purpose i am using woocommerce registration page comes with the plugin. now i need to create a function on wordpress with using woocommerce or without using woocommerce, so that when a user register on wordpress it automatically creates a account on my project management database. So when a user logins to wordpress also login to the project management without entering login information again. Here is the fields on users table of project management.
id (auto increment),
username,
password,
email,
user level (can be set within function)

i can create a custom registration page for wordpress if needed, i searched a lot but found nothing like this. I only find the methods to use external login on wordpress,  find no where how to create wordpress users on external db. Thanks for advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you code you PMS to use users from WP? Or do you need users to be created in the DB for your PMS?

Comment: i need users to be created in the DB of PMS so i can assign projects and invoices to user.Thanks

Comment: hello did you find an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You probably should create a WordPress plugin for this purpose.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

There are filter hooks that intercept the creation of new WordPress users; you can implement your code there.

There's one filter hook called `'wpmu_validate_user_signup'`. In that one your filter function gets called with a new user's profile information. You can write PHP code to access your PMS's database to set up a shadow account for the user there.

There's another called `'pre_user_login'`. This is called shortly before a user logs in. You can probably do what you need to do in those two hooks.

Notice that writing a WordPress plugin requires you to learn a lot about how WordPress works. It also requires you to read the WordPress code for the sections you're working with.

Comment: i am extremely efficient in playing with wordpress themes and templates, But didn't work with plugins, So i need to learn few things to achieve. Btw thanks for your kind help. Much appreciated.